# Sprite disappearing when I am trying to move it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

Im trying to get my sprite to move on touch but seems to disappear on touch then reappear on second touch . I do not know how to fix this to get my sprite to move at the direction I tap.  I have been trying to figure this out for a while but seems I am out of luck. I am hoping someone can point me at the right direction.

```
      CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
     player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Player.png" 
                                       rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 40)];
     player.position = ccp(player.contentSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    [self addChild:player z:1]; 










          (void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
        {
          [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self 
                                             priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
    }

        -(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
         {
        return YES;

     -(void)setPlayerPosition:(CGPoint)position {
      player.position = position;
    }

     -(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
     {

   CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];       
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];
    touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

    CGPoint playerPos = player.position;
     CGPoint diff = ccpSub(touchLocation, playerPos);
     if (abs(diff.x) > abs(diff.y)) {
         if (diff.x > 0) {
    playerPos.x += contentSize_.width;
} else {
    playerPos.x -= contentSize_.width; 
}    
   } else {
if (diff.y > 0) {
      playerPos.y += contentSize_.height;
} else {
    playerPos.y -= contentSize_.height;
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your touch function seems to be different.

try this code instead

```
- (void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];       
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];

    CGPoint playerPos = player.position;

}
```